# Allow registered user to access their account without doing login

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am sending link to an registered user. When they click the link i want them to redirect to access

their account without any authentication(login). But when they access site normally they

should do login. I am using `Digest/sha` for password encryption.Any one have idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Following..

You have to send the link to their mail account.

so user can access the account with in 5 minutes.

After Five minute this link is not worked.
You have to pass the some unique key with the link.
like.

> www.google.com?id=12d123e33ert

You have to generate unique link each and every request for user.
And store into one database table. with the Email ,timestamp.
If user dont click to this link within 5 minutes.

you have to clear the database whose timestamp is bigger than 5 minutes using the crone job Functionality of the server.

If Eamil and link key is matched with our store key than user can access the website.
otherwise not.

You got my Point?

Comment: You don't need to clear the link with a cronjob. Just check the timestamp when the user clicks the link.

Comment: But here the problem is, This table contains the so many entry then speed of the searching is slow...

Comment: If you want to save the login histroy.

Comment: then you can move it onto another table.you have to clear the this table.For speedly login.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to use a lot of the same logic that the forgot password functionality uses here in this Railscast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password